# msaccess finding queries that contain certain text

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to write a query that lists the queries in an access database containing a certain text "TEXT"

I looked online, and found this:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (([Type] = 5) AND ([Name] Not Like "~*") AND ([Name] Not Like "MSys*"))
ORDER BY [Name];
```

but my question is how do I find the actual text in the query

Comment: This might be useful. You look in the QueryDef objects  http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=197449

Answer (score 3):

After some searching I was able to write/find this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects INNER JOIN MSysQueries ON MSysObjects.Id = MSysQueries.ObjectId
WHERE (((MSysQueries.Expression) Like "*TEXT*") AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=5));
```